# Distribute Gitlab pipeline across different clients

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a pipeline, where some tasks can only be processed by certain clients. For instance, some clients can only perform certain tests, where other clients are used to compile. Can I distribute my pipeline chain across different clients? For instance:

```
                         /--- Testing (test-client-1)--\
Build (build-client-1)--+                               +-- Package (build-client-1)
                         \--- Testing (test-client-2)--/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign specific tasks to different runners, using tags: see [runners/#using-tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/#using-tags) and [README.html#tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#tags)

```
job:
  tags:
    - ruby
    - postgres
```